# Unencrypt an excel file (xls, xlsx, 2003 onwards) with the password

Tags: excel, encryption

I have some excel files that are password protected and encrypted using excel. I know the password but I do not want to use excel or excel automation to open them. Is it possible to remove the encryption without running excel itself?

If I knew what encryption type was selected when it was encrypted would this help?

Comment: i dont think its possible without opening the file. my suggestion would be to write a vbscript that will open each file with the Visibility set to false, remove the password and close the file.

Comment: How about if it was just xlsx. Would it be possible with the Open Xml SDK?

Comment: Maybe [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)? Or [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: I found this one https://code.google.com/p/ooxmlcrypto/ which looks promising

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries which can deal with Microsoft Office encrypted/signed documents.
Don't know about free ones, but SecureBlackbox should be able to do what you want.